# Textview should be placed higher on the screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I added a link in my textview, but for some reason, the entire textview gets placed in the center of my screen, instead of on top. I've added the image where it shows the wrong placement.

Does anyone know why this is, and how I can fix it?

Here is my main activity code:

```
package com.example.rodekruis;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FoldersActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{


     TextView HyperLink;
     Spanned Text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_folders);

        findViewById(R.id.button11).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button12).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button13).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.button14).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.imageButton1).setOnClickListener(this);

        TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String text = getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_folders);
        text += "<a href='https://www.rkz.nl/overzicht'> Klik daarvoor op deze link</a>";
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = null;
        switch (v.getId()) {


            case R.id.button11:
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/RKZ.BrandwondencentrumBeverwijk");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                break;
            case R.id.button12:
                Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/user/rodekruisziekenhuis/featured");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri1);
                break;
            case R.id.button13:
                Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/rodekruiszh?lang=nl");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri2);
                break;
            case R.id.button14:
                Uri uri3 = Uri.parse("https://www.linkedin.com/company/rode-kruis-ziekenhuis");
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri3);
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton1:
                intent = new Intent(FoldersActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
                break;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Here is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Folders" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:src="@drawable/informatiebutton" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollview"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="364dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_folders"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />




</ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the image to show the wrong placement of the textview:

[image]

Comment: textview gravity=start

Comment: Remove this: `android:layout_gravity="center"` from the textview

Comment: android:layout_gravity="center" remove it and set the you have where you view Textview.

Comment: `Text View` contains this `android:layout_gravity="center"` so remove that property. Or else change the value of that to `android:layout_gravity="top"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this xml code.instead of `android:layout_gravity="center"`  use             `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Folders" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:src="@drawable/informatiebutton" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollview"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="364dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_folders"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
</ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, pretty obvious, but I couldn't seem to find it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the marginBottom of the last ImageView and the marginTop and layout_gravity of the TextView.